# Aggregating but not taking the first result

Tags: views

I have a set of profiles, and some users have two of the same type.

Well one of the views gets around these duplicate profiles by aggregating them. The problem is that it grabs the first of the two duplicates.

Provided that programmatically removing the extra member profiles isn't really feasible, is there a way to grab the second of the two duplicates?

A sample of the query is here:

```
select DISTINCT p.pid, p.type, p.uid, u.name from profile as p
join users as u on (u.uid = p.uid)
where p.type = "member"
group by u.uid
order by p.uid, p.pid DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module, like so:

1. Create a view "user profile" master (not page)

   - use contextual filter user UID
   - In the pager: Display a specified number of items : 1 item and set offset to 1
2. Create the main view

   - add global field view
   - use user uid as a contextual filter

**The problem with this is that if user have only one profile then you may encounter a problem** but maybe you can change it
for more detail on how to create view inside view check [Drupal Views Inside Other Views](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-field-view/).